# How to trace function call in Erlang ?

Tags: debugging, erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a function in my_sup.erl like this:

```
init([ems_media_sup]) ->
  {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, ?MAX_RESTART, ?MAX_TIME}, [
   {ems_media_sup, {ems_media, start_link, []}, temporary, 2000, worker, [ems_media]}]
}};
```

But there is no function named start_link/1 in ems_media.erl, I want to know why there is no error when run

```
supervisor:start_link(?MODULE, [ems_media_sup])
```

So, How to know what happened next after call init([ems_media_sup])

Answer (score 3):

That's because `my_sup` is of type `simple_one_for_one` - so it will only start child processes when explicitly asked to do so through [supervisor:start_child/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2).

If the supervisor had been of any other type (`one_for_one`, `one_for_all` or `rest_for_one`) it would have attempted to start all children in the child specification at startup, but a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor is for creating large numbers of children that only vary by their argument list, so in that case the child specification in the `init` function only plays the role of a template.

Comment: Good answer I think, will dive into it later